# Discord.py int has no attribute send

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hey so I got this code

```py
import discord
import asyncio
import random
import os
import time
from discord.ext import tasks, commands


client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
 print('we have logged in as {0.user}'.format (client))

async def background_loop():
  await client.wait_until_ready()
  while not client.is_closed():
    channel =(814588208091365426)
    messages = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]
    await channel.send(random.choice(messages))
    await asyncio.sleep(60)
    

client.loop.create_task(background_loop())
client.run(os.getenv('token'))
```

and I am getting this error:

```
future: <Task finished name='Task-1' coro=<background_loop() done, defined at main.py:15> exception=AttributeError("'int' object has no attribute 'send'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 20, in background_loop
    await channel.send(random.choice(messages))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'send'
```

I also tried adding

```py
return messages
```

I didnt get an error but the bot also didnt do anything.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call the function `send` on the number `814588208091365426`, this is the channel id, you need to convert the channel id to a channel with:

```
channel = client.get_channel(814588208091365426)
```